# Transitions Stopped Working after Xcode Update

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Today I updated Xcode and then all my transitions in all my apps from the last few years stopped working. I tested running them on the new simulators and also by installing to iOS13.2 devices. However, transitions work fine when I download any of my apps from the App Store. I will try new builds on test flight in a moment. Maybe I've been doing something wrong al along these years?

Transition Code

```swift
let details = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewSettings")
details?.transitioningDelegate = self.slideAnimatorLeft
self.present(details!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Transition Class

```swift
class SlideAnimatorLeft: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    let duration = 0.9

    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        return self
    }

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return duration
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        guard let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.from) else {
            return
        }

        guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to) else {
            return
        }

        let container = transitionContext.containerView

        let screenOffUp = CGAffineTransform(translationX: container.frame.width, y: 0)
        let screenOffDown = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -container.frame.width, y: 0)

        container.addSubview(fromView)
        container.addSubview(toView)

        toView.transform = screenOffUp

        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.8, initialSpringVelocity: 0.8, options: [], animations: {

            fromView.transform = screenOffDown
            fromView.alpha = 1
            toView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
            toView.alpha = 1

        }) { (success) in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(success )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line your code.

```
 details?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
```

// complete code

```
 let details = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CollectionViewController")
 details?.transitioningDelegate = self.slideAnimatorLeft
 details?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
 self.present(details!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `modalPresentationStyle` to `custom` like this:

```swift
let details = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewSettings")
details?.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
details?.transitioningDelegate = self.slideAnimatorLeft
self.present(details!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```